# Semi Join on String

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I have a junction object called `Trip_meeting__c` to connect `Event` to `Business_trips__c`. Because you can't create a lookup to `Event`, I am using a *text field* `Meeting__c` to hold the `Event` Id and will query on that field.

I can do a semi-join on the junction to the custom object parent since it is linked via lookup:

```
Event EV;

public List <Business_trip__c> getBizTrips (){
    return [
        SELECT id, name, ownerID, start_date__c, end_date__c, location__c
        FROM business_trip__c WHERE Id IN (
            SELECT Business_trip__c FROM Trip_meeting__c
            WHERE Meeting__c =: String.valueOf(EV.id)
        )
    ];
}
```

But doing the same for the `Event` runs an error:

```
Business_Trip__c BT;

public List <Event> getEvents(){
    return [
        SELECT Id FROM Event WHERE Id IN (
            SELECT Meeting__c FROM Trip_meeting__c WHERE Meeting__c =: BT.id
        )
    ];
}
```

> semi join sub selects can only query id fields, cannot use:
>   'Meeting__c'

Since `Meeting__c` holds the Id of the `Event`, how can I query using this field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're going to need to do plain old pre-processing.

```
Set<String> meetingIds = new Set<String>();

for (Trip_Meeting junction : [
    SELECT Meeting__c FROM Trip_Meeting__c WHERE Business_Trip__c =: BT.id
]) meetingIds.add(junction.Meeting__c);

return [SELECT Id FROM Event WHERE Id IN : meetingIds];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Set and populate it with all the values in Meeting__c.

Technically this field is a text field so that's why you can't use it in your query.